# Getting unique id in firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire

I am using firebase for a project and I am trying to get all of my objects from the database, I am running this piece of code to get them:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<fire-base-database>.firebaseio.com/games");
$scope.games = $firebaseArray(ref);
```

I am getting the objects correctly but when I try to access their ID's with `.$id` I am not getting any data back...

Is there any way of getting the object unique id (which looks something like **`JlTq-W2RtWpOuKb2_Gp`**)? I need it to show the detail view of the item when someone clicks on it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to solve this by getting the key in the ng-repeat like `(key, games) in games` and it gave me access the key.

Comment: Nice approach. Thanks